# problem in batch file

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to run this code:

```
Set a = "c:\a"
set b = "c:\b"
xcopy /d /y %a  %b
```

But I don't know why it cannot recognize the second path.

The export in cmd is like `xcopy /d /y c:\a`

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have spaces before and after the "=" sign when setting the variables. And as Ignacio said, variables should end and start with %

So this should work correctly:

```
set a="c:\a"
set b="c:\b"
xcopy /d /y %a% %b%
```

Answer (score 2):

Batch variables begin and end with a `%`.

```
xcopy /d /y %a% %b%
```

Comment: The result in cmd is "xcopy /d /y"!!!!

Comment: @rima: because ignacio left out the "obvious" 2 `set` commands ...